# Firefox WebIDe is not detecting Jio Phone

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I am trying to develop an app for jio phone but I am not able to connect phone to the WebIDE. I enabled "ADB and Dev tolls" in Developer options, even then the IDE is not detecting the phone. Am i missing something or is there any different IDE that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

I cant find debugging options in my phone (f41t) so i unpack and repack boot.img. and added adb and debugging lines in default.prop but i cant able to flash it back.
Device- jio f41t 
Chipset- spreadrum 8830
Note- Extracted boot.img from firmware.pac file

Answer (score -1):

First check whether your os detects the jio phone by issuing command
"adb devices" in terminal. Then check whether webide detects your phone.
Anyway i was trying to do the same but couldn't test it myself because i accidentally updated my firmware to a newer version and the new firmware has no usb debugging option(or it might be possible that i'm not able to find that option). Please let me know ,if you can find usb debugging option there or if can find a way to downgrade the firmware so that i can check that myself.

Comment: There is no option to enable developer options in the latest firmware and there is no way to go back to the old one.